# Script error in IE in Microsoft Graph c# connection example

Tags: internet-explorer, oauth, microsoft-graph-api

I have a c# application which accesses Microsoft Graph. Since today the login with a Microsoft account is no longer possible as the login dialog displays a script error `Object doesn't support this property or method "startsWith"`:

[image: Screenshot of script error]

The code for the log-in is taken from an official [Microsoft Graph C# Console Connect Sample](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/console-csharp-connect-sample) and I can reproduce the error by running this sample as well.

As far as I can tell, the login dialog opens an Internet Explorer instance and navigates to the URL specified in the error (https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize) and indeed visiting this URL in IE produces the same error:

[image: Screenshot script error IE]

I know that two days ago the login still worked with the same code.

Can anyone reproduce this behavior?

Is there a way to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

We're seeing the same error when our app redirects to https://login.microsoftonline.com/companyname/oauth2/authorize to log in.

That page uses startsWith() which isn't supported by Internet Explorer according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith

It's also only started happening over the last 1 - 2 days.

There's polyfills for startsWith() but the page is obviously out of our control.

We were able to get around it by clearing cookies/local and session storage then reattempting the auth process - but that's obviously not ideal.